# Best Practice Multiple Address Lookups Google API Using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, google-api

The end goal is, given a large set of addresses, get 'lat' and 'lng' from Google API geocoding service (which I can do).  Then, parse the data so that lat and long can go into into a pandas dataframe at the same row as the address provided (which I can also do).

My data set is going to expand, but I got stuck parsing a small subset of this as I want to avoid doing **for** loops through data frames as that will likely be sluggish when the data set goes from 30 rows to multiple thousands.

Here's where I started:

```
import pandas as pd
import googlemaps
```

Read in dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv("SmallDecember2018")
```

## connect

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='shhhItsSecret')
```

## get the geocode for each item based on addresses (AddressConcat) in my file, put them into the df.

```
df['geo_result'] = df['AddressConcat'].apply(lambda x: gmaps.geocode(x))
```

This works fine.
I get data into the `df`, but it's somewhat awkward. Python sees it as a List with an embedded dictionary.

To get the first row of data I want from the `df`, this code works for the elements I care about

```
lat = df['geo_result'][0][0].get('geometry').get('location').get('lat')
lng = df['geo_result'][0][0].get('geometry').get('location').get('lng')
print (lat + " " lng)
```

ideally, I wanted to do another lambda function to look at `['geo_result']` and parse `lat/lng`

I tried, just for 'lat'...

```
df['lat'] = df['geo_result'].apply(lambda x: df['geo_result'].[x][0].get('geometry').get('location').get('lat')
```

It doesn't seem to like this approach as the `lambda` function doesn't want to hash a dictionary or a list - I tried going both ways.

Is retrieving it into a dataframe via lambda funct going to be performant at 2-3k requests at a time?  I have a GCP account, and could put them in BigQuery if that's a recommendation so long as I can get it to a DataFrame eventually.
How should i format it once I get the response? (json? dictionary?)
How should I parse the data on return (for loops or is there a smoother way?)

I'm starting with Python, but not married to it as I'm looking for more direction and recommendations than code. I'm trying not to hack this part of it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be clear, my end goal is that I want to find an efficient process to get it out of the native response format provided by google (which I have), and move the 'lat and 'lng' elements into their own column efficiently.

Comment: Is it an API call per address? (That's the part that's going to be sluggish, not pandas!)

Comment: Thanks @AndyHayden, that's true.  they throttle requests.  So I know there is built in latency there.  Perhaps another question - is there a documented way to get more than one address in single python request so that I can get multple geo locations?  If you are aware of that site/documentation, that would be useful to me as well...

Comment: I think not, I have used this API before and not come across that (for me it would also be useful)

Comment: Agree, there's a use-case for a single request for multiple addresses/responses...

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the API / lookup in a pandas apply.

I recommend splitting out this into two functions (if it's tens or hundreds of thousands I'd use SQS or Pub/Sub to parallelize the address lookup and store the result into a database). If it's a few thousand I'd just do this locally:

Loop through each address (from a csv file) and store the response to a file (probably the hash of address.json, or some other unique identifier). *I might split the csv into a few pieces and run it in parallel/with several python instances (depending how slow it was)...*

Once complete as a separate python script I'd loop through each file and parse it to a list of dicts (and convert that to a pandas DataFrame - and csv).

Comment: Pub/Sub is an intriguing idea, but overkill for this.  On everything else, I follow you.  This gives me some guidance on where/how to optimize which is what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: I have done similar with SQS / have some tooling in our company to make that easy (spool up a few hundred servers to execute this kind of stuff). Definitely over kill for only a few thousand!